# Gerenciamento de estado com Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Boa tarde, Estou com um problema, estou com meu código abaixo, e nele faço o seguinte, quando abre a tela pela primeira vez ele busca dados de uma api e salva no banco. Logo o usuário pode fechar o app e abri-lo novamente, quando ele abre a tela e já tem os dados ele pesquisa direto no banco de dados e preenche o PaginatedDatatable, acalma a segunda opção funciona corretamente, os dados do banco estão bem, o problema esta quando executo a api, dentro da api já tem o processo de salvar no banco, salva certo sem problemas, mas espera lá e não preenche meu PaginatedDatatable, segue o código abaixo de tudo, obrigado pela ajuda.

```
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
import 'package:....../conexao/endpoints_api.dart';
import 'package:....../api/produtos/produto.dart';
import 'package:balanco_app/helpers/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:balanco_app/models/dados_acesso.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ListaDeProdutos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListaDeProdutosState createState() => _ListaDeProdutosState();
}

class _ListaDeProdutosState extends State<ListaDeProdutos> {

  DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper();
  Endpoints endpoints = Endpoints();
  bool sort;
  Color primaryColor;
  int _rowPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  String sCnpj;
  String sUser;
  String sChave;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    resgataDados();
    sCnpj = context.read<DadosAcesso>().cnpjInicial;
    sUser = context.read<DadosAcesso>().usuario;
    sChave = context.read<DadosAcesso>().codAcesso;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    primaryColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    DTS dts = DTS(context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd);

    setState(() {
      dados();
    });

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: db.getAllProdutos(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                PaginatedDataTable(
                  sortColumnIndex: 1,
                  columnSpacing: 3,
                  dataRowHeight: 55,
                  horizontalMargin: 3,
                  headingRowHeight: 30,
                  header: Text('Lista de Produtos'),
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Cód.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Descrição',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'QTDE',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],


                  source: dts,
                  onRowsPerPageChanged: (r) {
                    setState(() {
                      _rowPerPage = r;
                    });
                  },
                  rowsPerPage: _rowPerPage,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return circularProgressGP();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  resgataDados() async {
    List linhas = await db.getDsDados();
    for (var linha in linhas) {
      sCnpj = linha['cnpjInicial'].toString();
      sUser = linha['usuario'].toString();
      sChave = linha['codAcesso'].toString();
    }
  }

  dados() async {

      await db.getAllProdutos().then((value) async{
        value.forEach((element) {
          context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.add(Produto(
              codbarras: element['codbarras'],
              desproduto: element["desproduto"]));
        });


        print('Lista length: ${context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.length}');

    if(context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.length == 0){
      await endpoints.resgata_produtos(sUser, sCnpj, sChave);

      context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.clear();

      await db.getAllProdutos().then((value) {
        value.forEach((element) {
          context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.add(Produto(
              codbarras: element['codbarras'],
              desproduto: element["desproduto"]));
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
    }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
    }
    
}

circularProgressGP() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            RotateAnimatedTextKit(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000) ,
                onTap: () {},
                text: ["Conectando...", "Buscando Dados...", "Aguarde..."],
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black),
                textAlign: TextAlign.start
            ),

          ],
        )
    ),
  );
}

class DTS extends DataTableSource{
  DTS(this.listProd);

  DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper();
  Material material = Material();
  final List<Produto> listProd;

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {

    assert(index >= 0);

    if (index >= listProd.length) return null;
    final row = listProd[index];

    print('Index: $index');

    return DataRow.byIndex(
        index: index,
        color: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected))
                return material.color.withOpacity(0.08);
              if (index % 2 == 0) return Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3);
              return null;
            }),
        cells: [
          DataCell(
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
              child: Text(row.codbarras),
            ),
          ),
          DataCell(
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
              child: Text(
                row.desproduto,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DataCell(
            Center(
              child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 110),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  //controller: qtde_controller,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    print("Texto digitado:  $text");
                  },
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => true;

  @override
  int get rowCount => 10;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado, pois sempre que a api roda e puxa os dados e salva no banco, mas não apresenta para mim em tela, a api esta certa, acredito que deve ser algo do PaginatedDataTable, agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: O que tem dentro do método `db.getAllProdutos()`? A sua tela só será atualizada quando você retornar algum dado válido na chamada desse método que o _FutureBuilder_ está escutando... Da forma que você fez chamando o método `setState(() { dados(); });` não irá desenhar nada em tela, pois dentro do _FutureBuilder_ você está validando se o mesmo possuí algum dado e não as propriedades da própria tela.

Comment: O metodo tem o seguinte:   Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllProdutos() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    print('passando...');
    return await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM produto');
  }

Comment: O que eu poderia fazer é colocar do dados() diretamente no no FutreBuilder, pode ser que de certo. Mas dai ele fica processando e não vem as informações. To perdido....

Comment: Fernando, não edite a pergunta adicionando "[resolvido]" no título. O [pt.so] não é um fórum de discussão. Você tem ferramentas próprias para sinalizar que a pergunta foi respondida. Veja em [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Se a resposta atual não atende 100%, faça a sua resposta explicando a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Você se perdeu em meio aos métodos assíncronos *await* e *then()*...

Existem duas formas de se fazer o que quer, mas irei focar na questão do *FutureBuilder*.

Primeiramente vamos modificar seu método *Dados()* da seguinte forma:

```
List<Produtos> dados() async {

    List<Produtos> produtos = []; 
    
    produtos = await db.getAllProdutos(); 
  
    if(produtos.isEmpty()){
      await endpoints.resgata_produtos(sUser, sCnpj, sChave);

      context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.clear();

      produtos = await dados();
    } else {
        produtos.forEach((element) {
          context.read<DadosAcesso>().listProd.add(Produto(
              codbarras: element['codbarras'],
              desproduto: element["desproduto"]));
        });
    }
    
    return produtos;
}
```

Dessa forma, utilizando apenas o *await*, seu método irá aguardar cada chamada para depois retornar para o seu *FutureBuilder* todos os dados disponíveis.

Agora é necessário ajustar seu *FutureBuilder*, vamos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: dados(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          DTS dts = DTS(snapshot.data);
            
          return Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                PaginatedDataTable(
                  sortColumnIndex: 1,
                  columnSpacing: 3,
                  dataRowHeight: 55,
                  horizontalMargin: 3,
                  headingRowHeight: 30,
                  header: Text('Lista de Produtos'),
                  columns: [
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Cód.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'Descrição',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                        'QTDE',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],


                  source: dts,
                  onRowsPerPageChanged: (r) {
                    setState(() {
                      _rowPerPage = r;
                    });
                  },
                  rowsPerPage: _rowPerPage,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return circularProgressGP();
        }
      },
    );
```

### Explicação

O *FutureBuilder* irá chamar o método *Dados()*, que por sua vez irá buscar no banco de dados toda a informação necessária, caso não encontre vai tentar requisitar para a API.
Feito isso, irá retornar os dados disponíveis para o *FutureBuilder* que irá disponibilizar os valores dentro de `snapshot.data` que no seu caso é uma lista de *Maps*.

Dessa forma, tentro do *FutureBuilder* após tratado todas as requisições, você pode fazer a chamada da sua classe *DTS*, caso exista informações disponíveis.

> Obs.: Como não nos informou o tipo da lista de produtos, joguei algo
> genérico `List<Produtos>`, ai tu faz as modificações necessárias...

Comment: Opa, agradeço a ajuda, fiz toda a modificação e os procedimentos que vc indicou, mas não obtive sucesso, fiz um print no retorno do builder para ver o snapshot, print(snapshot.data); e retorno null, o que será que pode estar errado?

Comment: Cara eu não havia visto o método `resgatarDados()`, eu modifiquei minha resposta, dê uma olhada... Peguei o conteúdo do método `resgatarDados()` e coloquei dentro do método `dados()`. Se você testar e ficar sempre "Carregando" vai ter que debugar e analisar melhor onde está o problema na chamada dos dados do banco. O Fluxo do precedimento no geral é o que está em minha resposta.

Comment: Bom dia, olha essa função de resgatadados(), serve apenas para pegar os dados para execução do endpoint, não tem relevancia, a primeira versão da resposta que vc colocou ficou melhor, mas ainda assim não mostra em tela, é como se o FutureBuilder não ficasse ali olhando o resultado por que o snapshot.data sempre retorno null. Fiz algumas modificações ali na função até que retorno, mas retorna apenas se ja tiver dados em banco, se fizer a execução do endpoint e dai mandar gravar os dados dai não da certo...

Comment: Fim de uma forma que deu certo, mas agora estou com outro problema kkkk, se tiver muitos dados ele demora para apresentar.. Saberia como resolver isso? Valeu muito obrigado.

Comment: Opa, se fosse trocar isso para um StreanBuilder, como que seria, por que vai ter um campo de busca e preciso atualizar o PaginatedDataTable, dai realmente acho que só com o StranBuilder né?

Comment: Cara, as perguntas aqui no site são para questões diretas para um problema. Você já está tendo dúvidas em diversos pontos... Pare e pense se essa mudança é realmente necessária e estude um pouco sobre os _Widgets_ citados, daí se necessário crie novas perguntas. (Talvez uma gerencia de estado como o BLoC ou Mobx possa te ajudar, vale dar uma olhada)

Comment: Valeu para resposta BEM DIRETA, "cara". Obrigado.